# Question about implicit functions of this form

Tags: real-analysis

I'm sorry I don't know how to make the title more descriptive.
Last year I learned in Calculus something I don't remember quite well, but I need it now for another subject, I just want to be sure this is right.

If we have a function$:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, given in the form:
$$h(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)=0$$

Is it true that the plot will be the two independent curves defined by $h=0$ and $g=0$, for example: $(x-1)(y-1)=0$, is that just the two lines $x=1,y=1$?, in that case it's true. Is the general case I wrote up also true, or not?

I only need it for something else I study, so I accept a yes/no answer, although some insight would be appreciated.
Thanks.

---

ADDED

After some discussion with amWhy, this is clear:
What I said happens if and only if the function h and g can be factorised into more functions of the same kind, for example the plot of this function:

$(y-x)(y-x^2)(y-3x^3)(y^2+x^2-1)=0$

will be all together the lines $y=x$, the parabola $y=x^2$, $y=3x^3$ and the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, which if it's factorised in more terms, then those terms will be plotted:
$(x^2-1)(y-1)=0$ will plot the line $y=1$ and the factors of the other term: lines $x=1, x=-1.$

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$h(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)=0 \quad?\implies? \quad h = 0,\;\text{and}\;g = 0$$

No, all that you know is that EITHER $\;h(x, y) = 0\;$ OR $\;g(x, y) = 0\;$ OR both are $0$.

Any of these cases will satisfy $\;h(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)=0.$

---

The solution to the equation: (*product* of any number of functions)$ = 0$ will be the union of the solutions to the equations (each function)$ = 0$.

Comment: And isn't there something like that? I remember something similar, like in my example, how do you deduce that?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking; the product of two function is $0$ iff one, or both, functions evaluate to zero. Put simply $a\cdot b = 0 \iff a = 0 \lor b = 0$.

Comment: It is true that the solution to your example includes, or is given by the two lines $x = 1$, $y = 1$.

Comment: I think you meant what I wrote about "or": either being a possibility. Perhaps I was nitpicking with the use of "and": each possibility. It is true that $h(x,y) = 0$ is a solution, and $g(x, y) = 0$ happens to be a solution. Essentially, I was simply pointing out that they *needn't both be zero*, so yes, there are two "independent" solutions, in that sense.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just remember that last year our multivariable calculus teacher told us something similar to what I was saying, like a trick when you see something similar to what I asked, but I don't remember very well what it was. It was that if you found two functions like I wrote, (not exactly like that but I don't remember), the plot would be the two independent functions. I have tried some examples and what I wrote is not correct, but it was similar. I just found some problems that might be usefull for and I would like to remember it.

Comment: Yes, you are right, when the product of two functions is zero, then each function equal to zero is an independent solution (does not depend on the other function).

Comment: To your last comment: I see, but no, it was something about the plots. Will you get two independent plots of the two functions? I've tried in Wolfram, and I don't, but it was something like that. Man, I think I won't be able to sleep tonight if I don't remember it

Comment: The plots will intersect when both functions happen to evaluate to zero., but that intersection just means it belongs to the two independent solutions, but happens to be equal to each other at the points of intersection: when both $h(x, y)= g(x, y) = 0$. If functions are independent, then their plots will be independent. Perhaps I'm not understanding what you mean by "independent". What I mean is that one of the equations/plots will not be impacted by, or will not vary, whatever the other equation/plot, and vice versa.

Comment: By independent I mean that in the plot it would be like if you ploted, independently, two functions h=0, g=0, for example in $(x-2)(y-1)=0$, you get that exactly: ) ( http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-2%29*%28y-1%29%3D0 (copy the whole link, the last part is being written as text) you get the line $x=2$, and $y=1$, it's even telling you that the function is a pair of intersecting lines. Another example: for $(x^2-1)*(y+2)=0$, that doesn't happen, and I think there were some cases in which that was always true.

Comment: That's because $(x^2 - 1) = (x + 1)(x - 1)$ and hence it's solutions $(x+1)(x-1) = 0$ are the lines $x = -1, x = 1$. Where as the other solution is $y = -2.$ So, in a sense, you should find that three lines result.

Comment: yes it helped. I still don't know THAT case my teacher was talking about, but you cleared some things. Don't delete it, and that last comment ilustrates why my second example wasn't working.

Comment: I have accepted it because you helped me get this clear. I have edited my firs post with my conclution.